# AWS - How to get username from token in a NodeJs Lamda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I use a NodeJs Lambda after an API Gateway.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'})
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const token = ...;
  const username = ...;
  const response = {
    "username": "...",
    firstname: "...",
    name: "...",
    email: "...",
    groups: []
  };
  return response;
};
```

I add a cognito Authorizer. With token, the result is OK and whithout the result is 403. is it OK for me.

exemple:

```
https://123456789.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/user/me
```

return:

```
{
    "username": "foobar",
    "firstname": "foo",
    "name": "bar",
    "email": "foobar@gmail.com",
    "roles": [
        "Admin"
    ]
}
```

* with foobar if foobar is in JWT and return toto if toto is in JWT

Now, I want return username of user (from JWT). My event is empty:

```
"event": {},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const claims = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims;
 const username = claims['cognito:username'];
```

before use this, I need use proxyLambda

[image]

and add this for the CORS (CORB):

```
   const response = {
     statusCode: 200,
     headers: {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(r)
  };
  return response;
```

or other solution: i do not use proxyLamba but you configure this:
[image]

after, you need decode JWT in Lambda.

```
const jwtToken = event.params.header.Authorization;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `return` is doing what you expect. Try using `callback`. Detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)

> Node.js runtimes support the optional callback parameter. You can use
>   it to explicitly return information back to the caller.
>
> callback(Error error, Object result); Both parameters are optional.
>   error is an optional parameter that you can use to provide results of
>   the failed Lambda function execution. When a Lambda function succeeds,
>   you can pass null as the first parameter.
>
> result is an optional parameter that you can use to provide the result
>   of a successful function execution. The result provided must be
>   JSON.stringify compatible. If an error is provided, this parameter is
>   ignored.
>
> If you don't use callback in your code, AWS Lambda will call it
>   implicitly and the return value is null. When the callback is called,
>   AWS Lambda continues the Lambda function invocation until the event
>   loop is empty.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'})
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) => {
  const token = ...;
  const username = ...;
  const response = {
    "username": "...",
    firstname: "...",
    name: "...",
    email: "...",
    groups: []
  };
  callback(null, response);
};
```